# SSIS 2012 Error-Unable to connect to Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssis-2012

I am facing the below Error when connecting to Integration Services from SSMS.I don't have SSIS 2005 installed,don't know what this error message is.

Please Help.

Connecting to the Integration Services service on the computer "localhost" failed with the following error: 
"The specified service does not exist as an installed service.".

This error can occur when you try to connect to a SQL Server 2005 Integration Services service from the current version of the SQL Server tools.

Instead,add folders to the service configuration file to let the local Integration Services service manage packages on the SQL Server 2005 instance.

Comment: You need to establish if SSIS is running as a service.  You can verify this from either Admin Tools->Services or SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm running into this with SQL 2016 and SSMS 2017 (the only one available to download, no v16).

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to SSIS from the local server or remotely?  The later SSMS versions (16.x and 17.x) will only connect to their respective versions. Microsoft is planning to retire this method in favor of the SSISDB, which is more secure.  [Link to the official statement from Microsoft (in the note box).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service#manage-the-service)

If connecting remotely, you may need to setup DCOM permissions.  [Browse to "grant permissions to the service" under the provided link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service)